# php looping through stdClass objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, stdclass

HI I using the woocommerce rest API to access order information made on a woocommerce site.

The data is being returned as json, I can access all of the data with this loop:

```
$orders = $connect->orders->get();
        $order_numbers = $orders->orders;

        foreach ($order_numbers as $order_number) {            

            $order_data = $connect->orders->get($order_number->order_number);

            echo '</br>' . $order_number->order_number . '</br>';
            echo $order_data->order->total . '</br>';

            $line_items = $order_data->order->line_items;

            foreach($line_items as $item){
                echo $item->name . ' x ' . $item->quantity . '</br>';   
            }

        }
```

The first line is the API call to get a lists of orders.

This allows me to output the data from the first object without specifying an order_number. However when accessing an array within the stdObject for example 'line_items' I have to define an order number. To overcome this I make another api call inside of the foreach this time specifying the order number to access the information.

```
$order_data = $connect->orders->get($order_number->order_number);
```

The problem is that this second API call massively slows down the entire page.

Is there a  way for me to reduce this to a single api call to speed up the page rendering.

For reference this is the data I am accessing:

```
object(stdClass)[15]
  public 'order' => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'id' => int 22
      public 'order_number' => int 22
      public 'created_at' => string '2015-07-30T14:01:54Z' (length=20)
      public 'updated_at' => string '2015-07-30T14:01:54Z' (length=20)
      public 'completed_at' => string '2015-07-30T13:01:54Z' (length=20)
      public 'status' => string 'on-hold' (length=7)
      public 'currency' => string 'GBP' (length=3)
      public 'total' => string '3.84' (length=4)
      public 'subtotal' => string '3.84' (length=4)
      public 'total_line_items_quantity' => int 2
      public 'total_tax' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      public 'total_shipping' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      public 'cart_tax' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      public 'shipping_tax' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      public 'total_discount' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      public 'shipping_methods' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'payment_details' => 
        object(stdClass)[17]
          public 'method_id' => string 'bacs' (length=4)
          public 'method_title' => string 'Direct Bank Transfer' (length=20)
          public 'paid' => boolean false
      public 'billing_address' => 
        object(stdClass)[18]
          public 'first_name' => string 'Chris' (length=5)
          public 'last_name' => string '#' (length=5)
          public 'company' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'address_1' => string '#' (length=4)
          public 'address_2' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'city' => string '#' (length=7)
          public 'state' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'postcode' => string '#' (length=7)
          public 'country' => string 'GB' (length=2)
          public 'email' => string '#' (length=20)
          public 'phone' => string '#' (length=11)
      public 'shipping_address' => 
        object(stdClass)[19]
          public 'first_name' => string 'Chris' (length=5)
          public 'last_name' => string '#' (length=5)
          public 'company' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'address_1' => string '#' (length=4)
          public 'address_2' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'city' => string '#' (length=7)
          public 'state' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'postcode' => string '#' (length=7)
          public 'country' => string 'GB' (length=2)
      public 'note' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'customer_ip' => string '#' (length=15)
      public 'customer_user_agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12H143 Safari/600.1.4' (length=134)
      public 'customer_id' => int 1
      public 'view_order_url' => string '#' (length=58)
      public 'line_items' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[20]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[21]
              ...
      public 'shipping_lines' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their specs (http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#view-list-of-orders) you should allready have all the information in your $orders result.

Comment: I do but the problem is when accessing the line_items array I have to specify an order ID which can only be done by an API call from what I can see. If I don't specify an ID I get a php invalid index error back.

And specifying the ID defeats the object of looping through all the orders.

Comment: as far as i can see the order-structure of both the view list orders and view order, the first just being an array of order objects.

why don't you try


foreach ($order_numbers as $order) {            
            echo '</br>' . $order->order_number . '</br>';
            echo $order->total . '</br>';

            $line_items = $order->line_items;

            foreach($line_items as $item){
                echo $item->name . ' x ' . $item->quantity . '</br>';   
            }

        }

Comment: Thank you so much. That woks perfectly.

I can see now comparing my code and yours what I was doing wrong. The page now renders instantly!